# Add CSS to existing website

Tags: html, css

I want to make a more mobile friendly version of this website: [auspuff-schuelerzeitung.de](https://auspuff-schuelerzeitung.de)
So I wrote this little CSS:

```
#slider-banner{
    display: none;
}

#secondary-right{
    display: none;
}

h1.site-info {
    display: none;
}
```

But how can I implement it into this website?

- I have no access to the server
- And I'm pretty new to all this stuff

Comment: No access to server???

Comment: Well **you cannot implement this without access to the server**. You need access to modify the code there. You could either add this to an existing style sheet - or create a new stylesheet and add a reference in the <head>

Comment: No access to server? so some day you would ask how to make css changes on google or stackoverflow huh?

Comment: I can not edit the html, because I have no access to the server

Comment: Obviously you can't modify random web sites on the Internet without access to the server. Either you'll have to ask the web site owners to implement this, or add the CSS locally with a browser plugin or similar. Neither of those solutions don't have much to do with programming so this isn't a very good question here.

Comment: if you dont have the access you can't make any changes there..

Comment: There is that Firefox add-on called stylish that is exactly what I would need, but without that add-on

Comment: 1.Download website source code  2 Implement locally

Comment: I have an own server can't I do something with PHP and an implode method?

Comment: do you have the access to the server where the site is hosted?

Comment: @Swordys the content is being modified online - I only want another version of that page for my app

Comment: clone the page code to the desired location add the css on the new page

Comment: @mahaidery but how can I clone it that the content changes like the original

Comment: looks like you are using Wordpress.. you can use a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-custom-cssjs/ to add that piece of code...

Comment: @mahaidery but I have no access to the server

Comment: Why do you want the change then?

Comment: do you mean to copy the site on your own server and make the change on your own server.. its so confusing.. pls clarify

Comment: @mahaidery I want to make some kind of mobile version of that website

Comment: ok take permission from the owner of the site.. use a software like htcopier.. that software will clone the entire site on your computer.. make the desired changes.. upload it to your own server

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>   <link rel='stylesheet' href='my_changes.css' type='text/css'/> <?php $_url = "https://auspuff-schuelerzeitung.de/" ; $_buffer = implode('', file($_url)); echo $_buffer;   ?> </body> </html>                         This was a trial but it's very bad and doesn't completely work

Comment: ah.. i got your point..

Comment: see my answer.. you need to place you custom css at the end of the document in order to make it override the style previously declared..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your clarification.. this is how you can do it..

```
<html>
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('https://auspuff-schuelerzeitung.de/');
echo $homepage; //you can strip the closing <html> if it bothers..
?>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='my_changes.css' type='text/css'/>


</html>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it

Comment: Thank you anyway for your afford!

Comment: whats your app? a web app or mobile? this code will work fine on all browsers

Comment: It's written with DroidScript, a simple program using java

Comment: without penetrate the custom css does it work on your app? i mean can you fetch the site on your app?

Answer (score 0):

- fetch latest copy of all files (`html`, `js`, `css`...)
- edit main.html's `<head>` and insert another `<link>` to the custom css file
- display page locally